# Makefile .o file rule issue

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to make a simple makefile to compile a sample app that I'm developing in linux (just to learn a few things) but I'm running into a strange issue, that I don't see why it's happening..

I have this makefile:

```
# Easily adaptable makefile for Advanced Programming

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS=-Wall -W -g -Wmissing-prototypes

# Indentation flags
IFLAGS=-br -brs -npsl -ce -cli4

# Name of the executable
PROGRAM=ex2
# Prefix for the gengetopt file (if gengetopt is used)
PROGRAM_OPT=config
# Object files required to build the executable
PROGRAM_OBJS=debug.o ${PROGRAM_OPT}.o

# Clean and all are not files
.PHONY: clean all docs indent

all: ${PROGRAM} 

# compile with debug
debugon: CFLAGS += -D SHOW_DEBUG -g
debugon: ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${PROGRAM_OBJS}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${PROGRAM_OBJS}

# Generates command line arguments code from gengetopt configuration file
${PROGRAM_OPT}.h: ${PROGRAM_OPT}.ggo
    gengetopt < ${PROGRAM_OPT}.ggo --file-name=${PROGRAM_OPT}

# Dependencies
${PROGRAM_OPT}.o: ${PROGRAM_OPT}.c ${PROGRAM_OPT}.h
debug.o: debug.c debug.h
main.o: debug.h ${PROGRAM_OPT}.h

#how to create an object file (.o) from C file (.c)
.c.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o core.* *~ ${PROGRAM} *.bak ${PROGRAM_OPT}.h ${PROGRAM_OPT}.c

indent:
    indent ${IFLAGS} *.c *.h
```

Once I type make, I get an error telling me that:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `config.c', needed by `config.o'.  Stop.
```

I might be missing something, but if I'm not mistaken, the line is explicitly there under PROGRAM_OPT

Here's the file list in the directory:

- config.ggo
- main.c
- debug.h
- debug.c
- makefile

Comment: What file(s) does `getgetopt` generate? Right now make only knows that it generates `config.h` so when you ask it (through `${PROGRAM_OPT}.o: ${PROGRAM_OPT}.c ${PROGRAM_OPT}.h`) to generate `config.c` it doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: @EtanReisner as I've said, I was under the impression that the makefile would execute the gengetopt command, which, by default, generates a .c and a .h file

Comment: It will generate it. But it doesn't know that it did that (and more to the point) it doesn't know that it should run that command to generate that file in the first place. make doesn't examine rule output to figure out what files the rule generates (and even if it did that wouldn't help with the first run).

Comment: Consider installing [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) and run `remake -x` for debugging `Makefile`-s ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This says that `make` can't find your source file `config.c`. You have a rule to make `config.h`, but I don't see one to make `config.c`.

Comment: Indeed that seemed to be the problem.. I was under the impression that once the makefile got to the line " gengetopt < ${PROGRAM_OPT}.ggo --file-name=${PROGRAM_OPT}" it would do what the command line usually does with that, which is, generate a .c and a .h file, based on the ggo..How come I have to explicitly tell makefile to generate a .c instead of just telling it to run that command?

Comment: I think it doesn't generate a config.c.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure ${PROGRAM_OPT}.c should not be referenced.

Comment: I think you are probably on the right track though I think you may have this backwards but explaining what you mean in more detail is a good idea.

Comment: @EtanReisner, you care to develop that matter a bit further? I'd really like to know more